# Visual Studio 2015 - Use C90 standard?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Is there a possibility to use the C90 compiler in Viual Studio 2015 (so new features are not available) ?

Background: In study we have to learn C using the C90 standard.

Comment: Unless something changed since I last checked, C90 is the *only* version of C supported in Visual Studio.

Comment: Why are they making you learn a 26 year old language?

Comment: @sepp2k: Visual Studio 2015 implements C99 (except for `complex`).

Comment: @librik They don't implement VLAs.

Comment: @2501: weren't VLAs made optional?

Comment: @librik They were in C11, but not in C99.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such facility in VS to disable certain C99 features, these are inherent part of "C mode". The Update 3 introduced [`/std`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/06/07/standards-version-switches-in-the-compiler/) switch, but it is only suited for C++.

You could validate the code against C90 after writing it in VS. For instance, you could use [gcc.godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/) online compiler passing following options:

```
-x c -std=c90 -pedantic -Wall
```